# Using Java Google Translate API

Tags: java

I am trying to use the [Java Google Translate API](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/), but I am having a problem setting it up. I create a package called javafx_texttospeech and put the two jars (gtranslateapi-1.0.jar and jl1.0.jar) in that package. I then create a class named Translate.

```
package javafx_texttospeech;

public class Translate{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
        String text = translate.translate("Hello!", Language.ENGLISH, Language.ROMANIAN);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

For some reason, this is not working and the keywords Language, Translator, and translate are being highlighted in red and it says that it can't resolve the symbols. What am I doing wrong? What should I import?

[image]

File structure:

[image]

Comment: Are you using eclipse (any other IDE) or java command line compiler to compile this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file menu -> project structure -> libraries

Then add your jar file there.

You can also import it from maven if it is on there. Putting it in you project folder won't work.

Comment: Got it! Now when I run it, it says Could not find or load main class Translator